# trying to installing rpy2 on Windows Vista

Tags: python, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2 package and getting following error both with

```
error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visu
al Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always hard to install `rpy2` on windows machines, there is no official binary.

I recommend you try the famous Christoph Gohlke repositories:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2

Or a `python` distribution such as Anaconda: http://continuum.io/downloads